# Load template from a string instead of from a file

Tags: django-templates

I have decided to save templates of all system emails in the DB.
The body of these emails are normal django templates (with tags).

This means I need the template engine to load the template from a string and not from a file. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instantiate a [`django.template.Template()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#compiling-a-string), passing the string to use as a template.

Comment: This will not use the backend configured in `settings.TEMPLATES['BACKEND']` but always uses Django's template system. Is there a way to create a Template from a string with the configured backend?

Comment: Get the backend from the settings, look up which Template() to use (have a map or introspect) and instantiate it.

Answer (score 15):

To complement [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2167281) from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, here is the code snippet that I use to get a template object from a string:

```py
from django.template import engines, TemplateSyntaxError

def template_from_string(template_string, using=None):
    """
    Convert a string into a template object,
    using a given template engine or using the default backends 
    from settings.TEMPLATES if no engine was specified.
    """
    # This function is based on django.template.loader.get_template, 
    # but uses Engine.from_string instead of Engine.get_template.
    chain = []
    engine_list = engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]
    for engine in engine_list:
        try:
            return engine.from_string(template_string)
        except TemplateSyntaxError as e:
            chain.append(e)
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(template_string, chain=chain)
```

The `engine.from_string` method will instantiate a `django.template.Template` object with `template_string` as its first argument, using the first backend from `settings.TEMPLATES` that does not result in an error.

Comment: I would love this answer if you could pass context to it

Comment: You don't need to pass context to it because it returns an unrendered Template object, then you have to call t.render(context, request) yourself after. I needed this solution for a specific use case and it worked great. However, chain does not appear to be an argument of TemplateSyntaxError, only TemplateDoesNotExist seems to use this which is the original exception get_template raised.

Answer (score 15):

Using django Template together with Context worked for me on >= Django 3.

```
from django.template import Template, Context

template = Template('Hello {{name}}.')
context = Context(dict(name='World'))
rendered: str = template.render(context)
```