# Django : HTML Table with iterative lists values

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django framework and trying to build a table based on the values i have in a list:

list : `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [3, 3, 3, 3]]` The table 
should be as shown below:

The code I have used is :

```
  html = "<html><body><br>" \
           "<table border=1 ><thead> <tr><th>result 1</th><th>result 2</th><th>result 3</th><th>result 4</th></tr><thead>{% for item in matrix %} {% for secitem in item %} <tr> <td> {{secitem[0]}} </td>  <td> {{secitem[1]}} </td><td> {{secitem[2]}} </td><td> {{secitem[3]}} </td>  </tr>    {% endfor %}{% endfor %} " \
           "</table></body></html>"
```

I am not able to get the exact table with the required rows in it. Any help is highly appreciated.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Your example table is invisible.

Comment: I am unable to upload image. However, it should be a 4X4 table with values of list present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over a list within a list, yet you are trying to access indices of an item within a list within a list.

Remove the "secitem" loop and access indices of `item` OR simply iterate over the `item`.

```
{% for row in matrix %}
<tr>
    {% for value in row %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with this code? I am still unable to get the result in tables:
html = "<html><body><br>" \
           "<table border=1 ><thead> <tr><th>result 1</th><th>result 2</th><th>result 3</th><th>result 4</th><th>result 5</th></tr><thead>{% for row in matrix %}<tr>{% for value in row %}<td>{{ value }}</td>{% endfor %}</tr>{% endfor %} " \
           "</table></body></html>"

Comment: or, if you want the headers: `<table border=1><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th></tr>` suggested code `</table>`

Comment: @GoutamAdwant that is correct. What is the output and issues you're still having? Note: if `<thead>` is present, you should add `<tbody>` around your primary rows.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I have removed <thead> from the code. The output i am getting is this : http://s15.postimg.org/vfjpc7597/image.png

Comment: @GoutamAdwant to me that looks like you need to compile your template. Rendering a django template in a view should be a separate issue altogether that I assumed you had already accomplished. Are you doing so?

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I could run the html page without any issues for other html codes but not in this one. Not sure when i am going wrong.

Comment: @GoutamAdwant are you compiling your template? If you are using an HTML string, django needs to run the template loader against it via something like: `template.Template(html).render(template.Context({'matrix': my_matrix})`

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I have used HTML directly in view.py and did not use any template. Here is my file structure snapshot
http://s11.postimg.org/6p1txuycz/image2.png

Comment: @GoutamAdwant if you are returning a python string, how do you expect django's template engine to have a chance to fire? `{% ... %}` is django template syntax. If you want to use the template engine from a string, you need to compile the template. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167269/load-template-from-a-string-instead-of-from-a-file here's one example. I suggest you do some research!