# Load the Rails view template from a string instead of a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a typical mailer setup in my Rails app with two views (.text.erb and .html.erb) for each method of the mailer class. These views are in the app/views/ directory and they are being properly rendered.

Now instead of rendering views which are in files in the app/views/* directory can I render a view whose markup template is in a string variable?

The template to be used varies based on the user and is picked from the DB. How can I render this ERB template which is in a string instead of rendering a template file in the views directory?

A very similar question, but from the Django world is this : [Load template from a string instead of from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167269/load-template-from-a-string-instead-of-from-a-file)

Please note : I do not want to capture the output of a rendered view as a string. There are several questions on SO about that.

Note to those who marked this as duplicate : This is not about controller views, but about mailer views. There are be two views for each mailer method and both views need to be rendered and then sent as appropriate contents in the email.

Comment: @Drenmi, & Simone Carletti : Added a note about why this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. This is simple

[`render inline: string_template`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

For mail views:

```
mail do |format| 
    format.html { render inline: string_template}
end
```

Comment: How would I do the same with the ActionMailer views? I typically call the `mail` method which I believe does the view rendering, that too both `HTML` and `Text` views. How can I achieve the same with this `inline` rendering?

Comment: mail {|format| format.html {render inline: string_template} }

Answer (score 1):

I would get my sting/template from the database, then render it inline with ERB.  This allows you to set instance variables and pass them to ERB via your local binding.  To me this is the most flexible approach.

```
def my_action
  template_from_database = "<h1>Hello <%= @instance_var %></h1>"
  @instance_var = 'World'

  render inline: ERB.new(template_from_database).result(binding)
end
```

Comment: Why the extra call to erb?