# How to compile a template saved in database in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am building an email sending application, I have many HTML templates stored in the database, So for each recipient, I need to customize this template by merging the tags/placeholders in the HTML,

example email template

```
<html>
 ....
     Hello {{ Name }},
 ....
</html>
```

So I need to compile this based on the context variables I have. Like we compile Django templates, How can I do this in the current scenario,

Tried, `render_to_string()` and `get_template()` functions, but they look for the actual template files stored in the `templates/` folder.

Comment: can't you store the email template file in one of those folders?

Comment: This is an email marketing application, where users create multiple email templates. this is why i am storing it in db.

Comment: Still This doesn't answer the question ;)

Comment: Can you mention the django version ?

Comment: Django 2 is the one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load template from a string instead of from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167269/load-template-from-a-string-instead-of-from-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods:

1. Use `from_string()` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine.from_string
2. Use Template object directly.

Example.

```
    from django.template import Template

    template = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
```

Comment: could you edit the answer a bit and format the code? I could accept this

Answer (score 2):

You can use django's template.Template Class

```
from django import template

html_template_str = "<html> Hello {{ Name }} </html>"

t = template.Template(html_template_str)
c = template.Context({'Name':"Name"})
html = t.render(c)
```

*html* will contain rendered template html