# How to process django url tags in context variables

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm creating a django-based website where page content is stored in a model textfield with a detail view of the model displaying it. How can I put {% url %} tags in the content to link to other pages without hard coding links?

Putting the tag into the textfield will just print the tag as plain text. (or if inside an href create a broken link)

Other options are

- parsing the content manually inside the view and replacing the tags with the correct url
- using some django supplied string parser to create the links before sending to the template
- maybe there is a way to do it in the template with a filter or tag around the variable.

I could probably do the manual way but I am hoping there is a django way that I am missing.

```py
class Page(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

class PageView(DetailView):
    model=Page
    context_object_name='page'
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ page.content|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Edit for clarity:

[Content in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrNj6.png)

[What it renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nit2U.png)

[What it should render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3C37.png)

Edit 2:
I was able to find a solution to the second option thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46756430/5183725) on another question. Using that template_from_string function I rendered the page content as a template then replaced the content in the context with the rendered result.

```py
class PageView(DetailView):
  model=Page
  context_object_name='page'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add to context here
    context['page'].content = template_from_string(context['page'].content).render(context)
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

your url's will have a name as shown below-
path('page//',PageView.as_view, name="page-detail")

and in your Page Detail

hope this is what your asking for

Answer (score 0):

Let see if I understood you well, do you want django to show you a url as such and not as plain text?

If you want to avoid django to show you the data as plain text, you can use the escape filter as follows: {{string | escape}}

Check [this page](http://django-book.blogspot.com/2012/07/apendice-f-etiquetas-de-plantilla-y.html) for more details about django filters and tags